# To pass parameter JSP to JSP

Tags: jsp

I have these pages: final.jsp and saida.jsp.

In the final.jsp I send the parameter:

```
<form action="saida.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="informal" value="${documento.stringInformais}">
    <button type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
```

then, I dont know how I need to receive the parameter in saida.jsp

Comment: Take a look at http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsp/pass-parameters-to-other-jsp-page/

Answer (score 2):

Jsp has implicit objects. Request and response can be used for receiving data.
So when you send from a form, you can request that data on the next page using JSP implicit object 'REQUEST'.

FOR example,

```
<form action="nextpage.jsp">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

on your next page you can retrieve this using request object.

```
<%
String name=request.getParameter("name");
%>
```

Similarly, you can use this code in you next page,

```
<%
String informal=request.getParameter("informal");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Query parameter**

```
<form action="saida.jsp?informal=${documento.stringInformais}">
    <input type="hidden" name="informal" value="${documento.stringInformais}">
    <button type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

you can send Using **Session object**.

```
   session.setAttribute("informal", "${documento.stringInformais}");
```

These values will now be available from any jsp as long as your session is still active.

```
   var informal= session.getAttribute("informal");
```

If the request from page A to page B happens to be invoked by a `POST` form, then you need to define the parameters as input fields of the form. If you want to hide them from the view, then just use `<input type="hidden">`

This way they'll be as expected available by `request.getParameter()` in B.jsp